# React router v6, on refresh of page whilst logged in, stay on that page, don't go back to "/dashboard"

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React router v6 and the Outlet component to render children.

When I'm on the url path "/predict-scores", which you can only reach if logged in, I want to remain on the page if the user refreshes the page, not go back to "/dashboard". Any ideas?

App.tsx:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { PrivateRoutes } from "./components/privateRoutes/PrivateRoutes";
import TopNavBar from "./components/topNavBar/TopNavBar";
import Dashboard from "./pages/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Predict from "./pages/predict/predict";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Reset from "./pages/reset/Reset";
import Results from "./pages/results/Results";
import { store } from "./store";

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                    <TopNavBar />
                    <div className="px-4 mt-4 grid place-items-center">
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                                <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
                                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                                <Route path="/results" element={<Results />} />
                                <Route path="/predict-scores" element={<Predict />} />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                            <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
                </Suspense>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRoutes.tsx:

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../../services/firebase/firebase-auth";

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

    return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the user in localStorage then I refer to this to control the Router. I have to use the redux user object to identify when the firestore has been logged out because react components cannot detect localStorage changes, only redux changes. useEffect will only re-render something after it detects a change, so I use the redux user as this reference in the dependency array.

PrivateRoutes.tsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { RootState } from "../../store";

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [userInLocalStorage, setUserInLocalStorage] = useState([]);
    const userDetails: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userDetails);
    useEffect(() => {
        const userObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scorePredictor") as any);
        setUserInLocalStorage(userObject);
    }, [userDetails]);
    return userInLocalStorage ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Setting and removing to LocalStorage:

```
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email: any, password: any) => {
    try {
        const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = res.user;
        localStorage.setItem("scorePredictor", JSON.stringify(user));
        return res;
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.error(logInWithEmailAndPassword, err);
        alert("logInWithEmailAndPassword" + err.message);
    }
}

const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("scorePredictor");
    return signOut(auth);
};
```

Comment: it's probably occurred due to the <React.StrictMode>, eliminate that in index and check it again.